# How to set focus on a TextBox from a ComboBox SelectionChanged Event in the same TreeViewItem

Tags: wpf, focus, treeviewitem

So the `DataTemplate` for the `TreeViewItem`:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ComboBox Name="CB" />
        <TextBox Name="TB" />
    </StackPanel>
<DataTemplate>
```

How can I put Focus on the `TextBox` when I change the `ComboBox` selection?

Answer (score 3):

If you put `FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=TB}"` on the `ComboBox` it'll send focus to the `TextBox` after you click the `ComboBox` open and closed (even if you selected nothing), which ended up working just fine for me, though I'm sure there's a better way.